# Does apache-airflow support Sybase as metadata db?

Tags: python, sybase, airflow, alembic

After setting `sql_alchemy_conn` to `sybase` connection string, `initdb` command is failing with below error. Is it because apache-airflow doesn't support Sybase as metadata db?

```
airflow initdb
...
...
{db.py:222} INFO - Creating tables
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda/bin/airflow", line 15, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 524, in initdb
    db_utils.initdb()
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 106, in initdb
    upgradedb()
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 230, in upgradedb
    command.upgrade(config, 'heads')
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 174, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 416, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 93, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 79, in load_module_py
    mod = imp.load_source(module_id, path, fp)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 74, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 65, in run_migrations_online
    compare_type=COMPARE_TYPE,
  File "<string>", line 8, in configure
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 773, in configure
    opts=opts
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 159, in configure
    return MigrationContext(dialect, connection, opts, environment_context)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.impl = ddl.DefaultImpl.get_by_dialect(dialect)(
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 65, in get_by_dialect
    return _impls[dialect.name]
KeyError: 'sybase'
```